# How do I fix this error while scraping? It says "certificate has expired"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, data-science

The website is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals_by_population
I'm trying to scrape the table with the national capitals

```
base_site = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals_by_population"

tables = pd.read_html(base_site)

URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)>
```

Why is this error message popping up? Also, there is more to the error message.

Comment: In this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oF-EMiPZQGA - (*at 2:45*) is added some lines for the certificate

Comment: Your code is valid, and is returning several dataframes. Someone might be MITMing you (like if you're on a corporate network and they are looking at traffic, or someone else is messing with your traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals_by_population"
s = requests.get(url).content
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
```